# How to control privacy in sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint, office365, privacy, privacy-policy

Office 365, SharePoint modern experience. I have a list of sales prospects where I want members of the site to only see prospects that have been assigned to them on that list by an admin. Basically, I don't want other reps seeing each other's prospects, let alone editing them. I thought if that I could just hide them, that would be sufficient.

I created the default public view to be showing only items that are assigned to [ME], and disabled members from creating or editing views. Sounded like it would work until I remembered search. I want each user to only see items that are currently assigned to them in search results, both site or team wide and in the list's search feature, for reasons explained above.

Can this be done in modern sharepoint? Seems to me that it can't. If not, does anybody have a good creative idea for handling a situation like this? I would hate to have to make an individual list for each person and override the parent's permissions and add/remove users for each one. Many users, and conglomerated reporting, power automations etc... gets way more complicated

Comment: It seems like question is not related to teams development. Could you please remove Microsoft-Teams tag?

Comment: The list in question is part of a ms team and is on the teams site, but I can remove it. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer but I didn't see any other answers. It seems as though the only way to do this is to use folders in the list with unique permissions for each. Yes, you can have folders in lists, and this situation would be the only reason I can think of as to why anybody would use them for a list instead of metadata and views. This takes care of any required filtering I was going to do using views AND, since it's permissions based rather than view based, it takes care of hiding it from others in the search results.

However, a few caveats.

Users have to make entries when inside their folder (the only folder they can see and have permissions to). If entries are made in the top level outside their personal folder, they will be seen, can be edited etc...by other members.

Second caveat is if you create any views with additional filters, you have to make sure you set your view to include results where content type equals folder, or else the user's folder will disappear when the user is at the top level outside their personal folder.

Third, you have to make sure you set any view view to display items inside folders rather than flat or else users will always be entering at the top level where it is not private.

This is still not perfect, and I had to disallow the manage lists permission and create personal views permission for members because they cannot be counted on to create new views properly given the requirements above. Fortunately, I don't want them creating those anyway. But this may not be an acceptable answer in some situations.